# Where can we define the Theme for Material-UI in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, material-ui

I am confused when setting styling for [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) based front-end.

Where does `theme` come from in the example code below and what are the effects of the theme?

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: "100%"
  }
}));

const Sample = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Container className={classes.root}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a provider of theme so called **ThemeProvider**

- document of material-ui [theming](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables)
- more customized usage [advanced theming](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#theming)

```
<ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme}>
  <Checkbox defaultChecked />
  <ThemeProvider theme={innerTheme}>
    <Checkbox defaultChecked />
  </ThemeProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

It provide the theme to the child components, we usually define this at the top level of the project.

---

Then you can access the `Theme` defined above via multiple ways

- [accessing-the-theme-in-a-component](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)

For example, for classical component we have **withTheme** HOC

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
function DeepChildRaw(props) {
  return <span>{`spacing ${props.theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
const DeepChild = withTheme(DeepChildRaw);
```

For functional component, we have **useTheme** hooks

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

And you can use them inside **makeStyles** and **createStyles** as normal

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: theme.spacing(1);
  }
}));
```

```
import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  root: {
    width: theme.spacing(1);
  }
})
```